# How to iterate elements of a hashmap over themselves and have them be mutable?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

So I have a hashmap that uses strings as keys and the values are my own struct for users. Which is just their name and position

```
pub struct User {
    name: String,
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}
```

Now what I want to do is iterate over the hashmap called users and see if two users position are close to each other, and then move them apart.

```
for (key, userA) in self.users.iter_mut() {
    for (key, userB) in self.users.iter_mut() {
        // collision code would go in here
    }
}
```

This causes an issue because users are then borrowed twice as mutable. I thought of getting around this issue by using mutex,

```
for (key, userA) in self.users.lock().unwrap().iter_mut() {
    for (key, userB) in self.users.lock().unwrap().iter_mut() {
        // collision code would go in here
    }
}
```

and the code compiles but it causes a runtime error later when I actually add an user to the map because of the second loop, since if I comment that loop out, the code runs with no issues. Any ideas on how I could write this differently?

Comment: Why don't you iterate immutably (using `.iter()` instead of `.iter_mut()`), then make a mutable borrow only when you need to make an update?

Comment: It complains that it also is borrowed as immutable without mutex at the start of the loop. With mutex it's fine when it comes to compiling, but from what I understand, mutex locks the first borrow in the loop which breaks everything.

Comment: Maybe you can collect the key pairs using nested immutable iterations and update the corresponding values based on the collected key pairs afterwards.

Comment: I see the issue now, this is actually a bit tricky. The most simple/performant option would likely be something like the `multi_mut` crate, but that seems a bit dubious. You might end up needing to wrap the hashmap values in `Cell` or `RefCell` for and using immutable iteration, unless @Joe_Jingyu's approach is suitable for your use case.

Comment: Did you try cloning the users HashMap?
`for (key, userA) in self.users.clone().iter_mut() {`
and then
 `for (key, userA) in self.users.iter_mut() {`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two stages. First you collect the collisions, and then resolve them. As an example:

```rust
let mut collisions = Vec::new();
for (key_a, user_a) in self.users.iter() {
    for (key_b, user_b) in self.users.iter() {
        if key_a == key_b {
            continue;
        }

        if user_a.x == user_b.x && user_a.y == user_b.y {
            collisions.push((key_a, key_b));
        }
    }
}

for (key_a, key_b) in collisions {
    // Move users apart.
}
```